# AT commands to send and receive an SMS using a ZTE MF637U modem

Tags: vb6, gsm

I'm developing a small application in VB6 to receive sms am using a ZTE MF637U modem,someone please help me with the AT commands to receive sms and also send?
the normal AT commands are not working with this modem.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp) is a great guide.

Before I switched to SMS using internet gateways, using the guide i was was able to send (AT+CMGS) and receive sms (AT+CMGL) via a usb mobile modem from mscomm control and vb6

Comment: the problem with internet gateways is that you cannot receive an SMS,do you have a way of receiving an sms through the internet?

Answer (score 0):

GSM modems use a different command set than regular modems and they vary by manufacturer.

Try this link for some guidance.

http://gatling.ikk.sztaki.hu/~kissg/gsm/at+c.html

Answer (score 0):

Try finding documentation specific for your phone, it might need some specific commands.

Alternatively use some existing library to do the job, like [libGammu](http://wammu.eu/libgammu/), there seems to be success with several [ZTE phones with Gammu](http://wammu.eu/phones/zte/) (though your particular model is not listed).